# Why can't I use TouchEvent in Safari

Tags: angular, typescript, firefox, safari, webkit

I have a project with Angular 8 where I want to handle touch events. Example handler:

```
@HostListener('touchend', ['$event']) onTouchend(event: TouchEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

I am running on MacOS 10.15 and this works fine i Chrome, but in Safari I get this error message and my app doesn't run: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: TouchEvent" and in Firefox "ReferenceError: TouchEvent is not defined". If I change the event type to any it runs in Safari and Firefox. Why can't I use the TouchEvent type in Safari?

Comment: how the hell could you have a typescript error in the browser ? Once your app is transpiled in JS, there is no type anymore, so the browser totally ignores it. Are you sure you're not missing something else ? Where do you import "TouchEvent" from ?

Comment: I think Safari believes TouchEvent is a variable for some reason. I don't import TouchEvent it is a part of the Typescript type definitions.
I tried to make a new empty Angular project and then just add the Hostlistener to a new component and there I don't get the error, so it is something in my code that is causing it.

Comment: are you "really" transpilling your ts into js ? Can you see the generated JS, and find the string "TouchEvent" inside the file ?

Answer (score 6):

Somewhere in your app add the following line:

`export type AppTouchEvent = TouchEvent;`

Then use `AppTouchEvent` in your ts files instead of `TouchEvent`.

Comment: What a bizarre bug. At least it's easy to fix.